# How was Moody allowed to turn a student into a ferret without getting fired?

Tags: harry-potter

I am confused as too how Moody (or fake Moody I suppose) was not fired or visibly reprimand for turning Malfoy into a ferret. I'm only asking this question due to the fact that Hagrid was almost fired for letting Buckbeak scratch Malfoy. It seems like Lucius would have liked to follow up on his son being turned into a rodent.

Comment: I think this likely has to do with Lucius not liking the Hagrid.

Comment: I suppose the punishment was more for endangering Malfoy than for harming him. Turning him into a ferret does not risk his life, while exposing him to a dangerous and apparently out-of-control beast  does. (Purely my own speculation, too tired to write up a properly sourced answer)

Comment: Ferrets aren't rodents, they're mustelids (weasel family).

Comment: Moody is not Hagrid... He can like scold Minister for Magic.

Comment: I suspect Lucius figured he could crap all over Hagrid due to Hagrid's low socioeconomic status, but would have been much more circumspect about picking a fight with a respected veteran Auror who seemed to retain a surprising amount of political capital. The Malfoys are bullies; they don't punch above their weight class, metaphorically speaking.

Answer (score 11):

Draco Malfoy might have complained to his father, because he mentions it.

> Malfoy, whose pale eyes were still watering with pain and humiliation, looked malevolently up at Moody and muttered something in which the words “**my father**” were distinguishable.
>
> “Oh yeah?” said Moody quietly, limping forward a few steps, the dull clunk of his wooden leg echoing around the hall. “**Well, I know your father of old, boy.…You tell him Moody's keeping a close eye on his son…you tell him that from me.…Now, your Head of House'll be Snape, will it?**”
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and The Goblet of Fire, Chapter 13, Mad-Eye Moody**</sup></sub>

Because there is no evidence of a complaint being made in the books. We could guess most probably the Triwizard Tournament saved Mad-Eye Moody. Lucius Malfoy might have complained, but it would have been embarrassing to fire a teacher when wizards from other schools and country would arrive at Hogwarts.

Secondly Moody was well respected unlike Hagrid and had provided service to the Ministry of Magic during the First Wizarding War.

> “Your father thinks very highly of Mad-Eye Moody,” said Mrs. Weasley sternly.
>
> “Yeah, well, Dad collects plugs, doesn't he?” said Fred quietly as Mrs. Weasley left the room. “Birds of a feather.…”
>
> “Moody was a great wizard in his time,” said Bill.
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and The Goblet of Fire, Chapter 11, Aboard the Hogwart Express**</sup></sub>

Moody's reputation for being fair to everyone (including death eater) might have helped him.

> “I'll say this for Moody, though, he never killed if he could help it. Always brought people in alive where possible. He was tough, but he never descended to the level of the Death Eaters.”
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and The Goblet of Fire, Chapter 27, Padfoot Returns**</sup></sub>

In any case, the matter was swept under the carpet.

Comment: Dumbledore never actually fired anyone, despite arguably having good reasons (Lockhart, Trelawney) to do so. The only time we ever see teachers fired was under the Umbridge administration. That may have been a factor.

Comment: I meant fired by the governors of Hogwarts.

Comment: The first quote seems to imply that Moody might have had some kind of blackmail on Lucius, such as his history as a Death Eater, or some other piece of information which would keep Lucius from pressing charges.

Comment: It could have been.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Malfoy may well have complained to his Father but Lucius was too scared of Moody to actually put in a formal complaint against him.

By the start of GoF Moody has a reputation for being slightly (understatement) unstable. This is seen at the start of the book with on page 160 when Amos Diggory says:

> "Arthur you know Mad-Eye", said My Diggory's head, rolling it's eyes again. "Someone creeping into his yard at the dead of night? More likely there's a very shellshocked cat wandering around somewhere, covered in potato peelings. But if the Improper Use of Magic lot get their hands on Mad-Eye he's had it - think of his record - we've got to get him off on something in your department - what are exploding dustbins worth?"
>
> "Might be a caution" said Mr Weasley, still writing very fast, his brow furrowed. "Made-eye didn't use his wand? He didn't actually attack anyone?"
>
> **"I'll bet he leapt out of bed and started jinxing everything he could reach through the window"** said Mr Diggory, "but they'll have a job proving it, there aren't any casualties."

and then later in the book on page 569 when Harry says:

> "D'you think it's too early to go and see Professor Moody?" Hermione said, as they went down the spiral staircase.
>
> "Yes" said Harry. **"He'd probably blast us through the door if we wake him at the crack of dawn"**

Given this, it is probable that Lucius Malfoy is scared that if he complains about Moody then Moody will hunt him down.

Another possibility is that transfiguration is not an altogether unusual punishment in the magical community despite it being not allowed at Hogwarts.

I say this because just afterwards, when McGonagall is talking with Moody she says:

> "Moody, we *never* use Transfiguration as a punishment!" said Professor McGonagall weakly. "Surely Professor Dumbledore told you that?"

The fact that Dumbledore would have need to tell Moody this suggests that there are places where transfiguration is used. Having said this, I don't believe that it being used in other places would have prevented Lucius from complaining. More likely to me is that he was scared of Moody.

Answer (score 1):

They *couldn't* fire Moody - he was *the only person available and willing* to teach Defense Against the Dark Arts, remember?  If they fired him mid-year, they probably would have had to cancel the course for the remainder of the year.  Parents would have been 'up in arms' over the damage to their childrens' education.  *[And during the Tri-Wizard Tournament to boot! How embarassing!]*

It was a bit different with the 'Buckbeak' incident - They could have replaced Hagrid by bringing Professor Grubbly-Plank out of retirement [as they did later when Hagrid was on the mission to contact the giants].

Comment: Can you provide sources for your answer? It would give it more credibility!

Comment: Well, there is Snape.

Answer (score 0):

He may have gotten a reprimand-- **We don't know that he didn't.**

We only know that he wasn't fired, but like Vishvesh pointed out it would have looked bad to dismiss a teacher in full view of wizards from other countries.  However, keep in mind that since the events of the story are being told from the perspective* of a (then) 14-year-old student, what conversations <strike>Crouch</strike> Moody may have had with other professors or Dumbledore, or really anyone outside of Harry's hearing, we wouldn't know.

*Sort of. (Third-person limited, if we're being technical)